# Spring boot + quartz scheduler + postgresql fails to create quartz related tables

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, quartz-scheduler

I am trying to create a Quartz scheduler microservice. Below is my Quartz configuration

```
@Configuration
@Slf4j
public class QuartzConfiguration {

    @Value("${spring.quartz.jdbc.initialize-schema}")
    String checkVal;

    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("appDataSource")
    DataSource dataSource;


    /**
     * @return map of properties to configure quartz
     */
    private Properties getQuartzProperties() {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put("org.quartz.jobStore.useProperties", "true");
        properties.put("org.quartz.job-store-type", "jdbc");
        properties.put("org.quartz.jobStore.class", "org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreTX");
        properties.put("org.quartz.jobStore.driverDelegateClass", "org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.PostgreSQLDelegate");
        properties.put("org.quartz.jobStore.dataSource", "appDataSource");
        return properties;
    }

    @Bean
    public SchedulerFactoryBean scheduler() {
        log.info("******************************* {} *******************************", this.checkVal);
        SchedulerFactoryBean schedulerFactory = new SchedulerFactoryBean();
        schedulerFactory.setJobFactory(springBeanJobFactory());
        schedulerFactory.setDataSource(this.dataSource);
        schedulerFactory.setQuartzProperties(getQuartzProperties());
        return schedulerFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    public SpringBeanJobFactory springBeanJobFactory() {
        AutoWiringSpringBeanJobFactory jobFactory = new AutoWiringSpringBeanJobFactory();
        jobFactory.setApplicationContext(applicationContext);
        return jobFactory;
    }
}
```

My `application.properties` is as follows
`spring.quartz.jdbc.initialize-schema=always`

The `datasource` bean is created by a separate library and successfully injected into the configuration class.

When I run the application the `scheduler` and all the beans corresponding to Quartz are created. However,  the tables related to quartz are not created. Due to the same, I get the below exception.

```
org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Failed to start bean 'scheduler'; nested exception is org.springframework.scheduling.SchedulingException: Could not start Quartz Scheduler; nested exception is org.quartz.SchedulerConfigException: Failure occured during job recovery. [See nested exception: org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.LockException: Failure obtaining db row lock: ERROR: current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block [See nested exception: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block]]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:185) ~[spring-context-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.access$200(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:53) ~[spring-context-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor$LifecycleGroup.start(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:360) ~[spring-context-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.startBeans(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:158) ~[spring-context-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.onRefresh(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:122) ~[spring-context-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:895) ~[spring-context-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:554) ~[spring-context-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:143) ~[spring-boot-2.3.3.RELEASE.jar:2.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:758) ~[spring-boot-2.3.3.RELEASE.jar:2.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:750) ~[spring-boot-2.3.3.RELEASE.jar:2.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) ~[spring-boot-2.3.3.RELEASE.jar:2.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) ~[spring-boot-2.3.3.RELEASE.jar:2.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1237) ~[spring-boot-2.3.3.RELEASE.jar:2.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226) ~[spring-boot-2.3.3.RELEASE.jar:2.3.3.RELEASE]
    at com.glidetech.scheduler.service.SchedulerApplication.main(SchedulerApplication.java:30) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.scheduling.SchedulingException: Could not start Quartz Scheduler; nested exception is org.quartz.SchedulerConfigException: Failure occured during job recovery. [See nested exception: org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.LockException: Failure obtaining db row lock: ERROR: current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block [See nested exception: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block]]
    at org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean.start(SchedulerFactoryBean.java:803) ~[spring-context-support-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:182) ~[spring-context-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    ... 14 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.quartz.SchedulerConfigException: Failure occured during job recovery.
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.schedulerStarted(JobStoreSupport.java:697) ~[quartz-2.3.2.jar:na]
    at org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler.start(QuartzScheduler.java:539) ~[quartz-2.3.2.jar:na]
    at org.quartz.impl.StdScheduler.start(StdScheduler.java:142) ~[quartz-2.3.2.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean.startScheduler(SchedulerFactoryBean.java:728) ~[spring-context-support-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean.start(SchedulerFactoryBean.java:800) ~[spring-context-support-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    ... 15 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.LockException: Failure obtaining db row lock: ERROR: current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.StdRowLockSemaphore.executeSQL(StdRowLockSemaphore.java:184) ~[quartz-2.3.2.jar:na]
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.DBSemaphore.obtainLock(DBSemaphore.java:113) ~[quartz-2.3.2.jar:na]
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.executeInNonManagedTXLock(JobStoreSupport.java:3857) ~[quartz-2.3.2.jar:na]
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.recoverJobs(JobStoreSupport.java:839) ~[quartz-2.3.2.jar:na]
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.schedulerStarted(JobStoreSupport.java:695) ~[quartz-2.3.2.jar:na]
    ... 19 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2532) ~[postgresql-42.2.14.jar:42.2.14]
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2267) ~[postgresql-42.2.14.jar:42.2.14]
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:312) ~[postgresql-42.2.14.jar:42.2.14]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeInternal(PgStatement.java:448) ~[postgresql-42.2.14.jar:42.2.14]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:369) ~[postgresql-42.2.14.jar:42.2.14]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeWithFlags(PgPreparedStatement.java:153) ~[postgresql-42.2.14.jar:42.2.14]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeQuery(PgPreparedStatement.java:103) ~[postgresql-42.2.14.jar:42.2.14]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(ProxyPreparedStatement.java:52) ~[HikariCP-3.4.5.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(HikariProxyPreparedStatement.java) ~[HikariCP-3.4.5.jar:na]
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.StdRowLockSemaphore.executeSQL(StdRowLockSemaphore.java:123) ~[quartz-2.3.2.jar:na]
    ... 23 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: relation "qrtz_locks" does not exist
  Position: 15
    ... 33 common frames omitted
```

I verified the following.

1. Whether values from `application.properties` are detected.
2. Whether `appDataSource` is available and configured.

I am not sure what I am missing. I appreciate any help.

Comment: Does this your answer of  question?  https://jeroenbellen.com/configuring-a-quartz-scheduler-in-a-clustered-spring-boot-application/

Comment: @priyranjan in the example you shared, the trigger and job are configured upfront. What I am looking to do is to create the scheduler bean and expose an endpoint via which a user can configure the job and trigger as per his needs.